# determine the formula of a dataset

Tags: r, statistics, extract, formula

I have a small dataframe that has a exponentially decreasing trend. I would like to extract a formula based on the data in my dataframe? Is this possible, and if so, how can I go about extracting the formula?

Comment: Sounds like you need some sort of polynomial fit: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting)

Comment: Hi nick - R can certainly do this for you, and SO can help. However - nobody can really provide any guidance without seeing what your data looks like. Here's a tutorial on how to ask a great question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Please update your question and I bet you'll get some high quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

To get a best fit exponential curve, you'll want to basically convert an the curve to a linear one, and find the "linear fit" and then convert it back. For example, here's data decreasing exponentially.

```
t <- c(0,2,4,7)
y <- c(25,11,4,3)
```

Then take the log of `y`.

```
y2 <- log10(y)
```

Then model y2 as a function of time.

```
lm(y2~t)
```

You'll get the slope and intercept in usual linear equation form (`y = mx + b`), but using log(y). To get the exponential equation of the line, put the slope and intercept into the following form:

```
y = A*r^t
```

Where `A = 10^intercept` and `r = 10^slope`.

For these data, your equation will be:

```
y = 20.77304*0.7333309^t
```

If you want to plot them together, define:

```
expLine <- function(t) 20.77304*0.7333309^t
```

Then `plot(t,y)` and `curve(expLine,0,7,n=101,add=TRUE)`.

Comment: If you want to plot them together, define: `expLine <- function(t) 20.77304*0.7333309^t`. Then `plot(t,y)` and `curve(expLine,0,7,n=2000,add=TRUE)`.

Comment: or `with(as.list(coef(lmfit)),curve(t*x+#(Intercept)#,0,7,add=TRUE))` (**note**, you'll have to replace # with a back-tick (single back-quote), comment syntax can't handle it).  `n=2000` is overkill for this problem; the default value of `n=101` should be fine.  By the way, @Amyunimus -- you're allowed and indeed encouraged to edit your question (this time I went ahead and did it for you ...)